# What is the default PHP configuration?

Tags: php, build, compilation, makefile, autoconf

What are the default PHP `--configure` flags, that are set when doing a standard LAMP install via tasksel? I have to recompile PHP to include process control for my buddy, but I haven't been able to find a list of all flags that come by "default".

Comment: tasksel is specific to Debian Linux derivatives.

Comment: It was on Ubuntu 10.04 I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `php -i | grep config -i` this should return what are the configure used by taskel.

**Backup** your php.ini before you proceed with re-compilation...

PS: you might need to download PHP source for compilation

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to recreate a previous compile so as to activate new modules, the `phpinfo()` output contains the exact `./configure` args used to create that version.

Comment: When I search on the page I can't find ./configure, and all searches for args are irrelevant. Is there a specific heading it is under?

Comment: On both cli and web-based versions, it should be the 3rd line. "Configure Command"