# Default PHP Config File

Tags: php

I'm looking to find a copy of the default php.ini file for PHP 5.2.17.

Does anyone know where I can get a copy to download?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [What is the default PHP configuration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473502/what-is-the-default-php-configuration)

Comment: http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.2-nts-VC6-x86?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/releases/index.php

Download: PHP 5.2.17 (tar.bz2) PHP 5.2.17 (tar.gz)

- http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.17.tar.bz2
- http://museum.php.net/php5/php-5.2.17.tar.gz

It's in the base directory (extracted).

"php.ini-dist" or "php.ini-recommended"

Answer (score 1):

There's a php.ini-dist and php.ini-recommended in the src, you may want to try that:

http://us.php.net/get/php-5.2.17.tar.gz/from/a/mirror

Comment: I wonder where you got you link from. It's an interesting URL.

Comment: Goooooooogle.com [min length required for comment]

Answer (score 1):

PHP Versions can be downloaded here: http://php.net/releases/index.php

You could also take a look at old versions of the GitHub repository: https://github.com/php

You are looking for the file **php.ini-dist** or **php.ini-recommended**.

Comment: It's cool that they have a github! It's just a shame that the web interface isn't subtle enough to directly "checkout <commit> <file>".